# Using Netbeans 8.2 and Ubuntu 19.4, compiling error

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, netbeans

Good morning/afternoon/night! (as applies)

Today I tried to test my new learned skills in Java, from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 19.4 (freshly installed) using NetBeans 8.2 (same version in both OS's), and in my first compilation for the sample JavaFX application (I mean, a new "empty" project), I got an error can't solve.

```
ant -f /home/felipe/NetBeansProjects/demoJavaFXApp jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: /home/felipe/NetBeansProjects/demoJavaFXApp/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/felipe/NetBeansProjects/demoJavaFXApp/build/built-jar.properties
compile:
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 12 files to /home/felipe/NetBeansProjects/demoJavaFXApp/dist/run309629545
jfx-project-run:
Executing /home/felipe/NetBeansProjects/demoJavaFXApp/dist/run309629545/demoJavaFXApp.jar using platform /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/home/felipe/NetBeansProjects/demoJavaFXApp/dist/run309629545/demoJavaFXApp.jar!/mx/com/tiammatsoftware/demoJavaFXApp/FXMLDocument.fxml:9
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at mx.com.tiammatsoftware.demoJavaFXApp.DemoJavaFXApp.start(DemoJavaFXApp.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: demojavafxapp.FXMLDocumentController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application mx.com.tiammatsoftware.demoJavaFXApp.DemoJavaFXApp
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory /home/felipe/NetBeansProjects/demoJavaFXApp/dist/run309629545
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Searched in The Net about that error and aparently is quite rare, 'cause found nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `FXMLDocument.fxml` refers to `demojavafxapp.FXMLDocumentController` while you seems to use `mx.com.tiammatsoftware.demoJavaFXApp` package. Probably correct class name should be `mx.com.tiammatsoftware.demoJavaFXApp.FXMLDocumentController`.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!! Saved my life!! :D

Comment: @TiammatMX glad to help :)